# Passing multiple string parameters in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv

When exporting data to csv with `Export-Csv` not all data is exported because not all fields show up in `Get-Member`(object properties are not equal between objects). I can, however, get them out by using `Select-Object`.

I can build this list dynamically, but I'm unable to pass it correctly.

Example:

```
$test = "`"Contract`", `"Hostname`", `"Description`"" //Code generated
$selected | Select-Object $($test)
```

How should I do this?

Comment: Your question is a little hard to understand. You're saying piping through select object doesnt work as intended?

Comment: An example of the csv file(s), and desired output would also be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an array of strings representing property names. For example:

```
$test = "Name","FullName","Length"
Get-ChildItem | Select-Object $test
```

Comment: Also:
Get-ChildItem | Select-Object $("Name", "FullName", "Length")